# api-platform/admin does not guess my Openapi endpoint

Tags: openapi, react-admin, api-platform.com

Despite the readme being very straightforward, I'm struggling to make api-platform/admin guess/discover my OpenApi endpoint.

I get the default empty react-admin page and the message in the console saying `If you want to override at least one resource, paste this content in the <AdminGuesser> component of your app:` despite having an `<AdminGuesser>` defined and I think properly configured.

I had a look at the [demo code](https://github.com/api-platform/demo/blob/main/pwa/components/admin/Admin.tsx#L120-L123), but it doesn't use the AdminGuesser (instead it hardcodes two `<ResourceGuesser>`) so I can't really check if it works.

Below is the code I used (adapted from the docs) and a screenshot showing the request to the openapi spec working with the admin staying empty and no js error.

Any hint at what I could be doing wrong ? Or a pointer to an existing demo/snippet achieving this ?

Thanks !

```js
import {
  AdminGuesser,
  openApiDataProvider,
  openApiSchemaAnalyzer,
} from "@api-platform/admin";
import { fetchUtils } from "react-admin";
import postgrestRestProvider, {
  defaultPrimaryKeys,
  defaultSchema,
} from "@raphiniert/ra-data-postgrest";

import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

// Configure endpoint from envvar
const endpoint = import.meta.env.VITE_SIMPLE_REST_URL;

const postgresProvider = postgrestRestProvider({
  apiUrl: endpoint,
  httpClient: fetchUtils.fetchJson,
  defaultListOp: "eq",
  primaryKeys: defaultPrimaryKeys,
  schema: defaultSchema,
});

// Setup dataprovider provider or resource schema analyzer
const dataProvider = openApiDataProvider({
  dataProvider: postgresProvider,
  entrypoint: endpoint,
  docEntrypoint: endpoint,
});
const schemaAnalyzer = openApiSchemaAnalyzer();

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <>
    <AdminGuesser dataProvider={dataProvider} schemaAnalyzer={schemaAnalyzer} />
  </>,
);
```

[image]